# Blockchain Explorer says received but it's not received yet!

Tags: transactions, receiving

I sent some Bitcoin to my friends wallet since 2 days ago. It says approved and sent successfully on my end. And even on blockchain Explorer it says confirmed and received. But my friend says he hasn't received any Bitcoin yet??? This is the transaction ID on blockchain Explorer

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/d350a1334d10e7693b56cc8fd8d11297080e1aebd9ffed97588a4b5f0929ca93

Answer (score 4):

> Blockchain Explorer says received but it's not received yet!

That's not how Bitcoin works.

All computer-based wallets, including your friend's, have a copy of the blockchain (or have indirect access to a copy). If the blockchain includes your transaction, then the money has been received. All copies of the blockchain are eventually identical, only the last block or two might very occasionally differ for a short while.

Note that you can receive Bitcoin even if your wallet exists only as a secret number written on a piece of paper. The blockchain is the true record of what has been received.

If your friend says their wallet has not received the money there are at least three possibilities

- They are lying
- Their wallet has not got an up-to-date copy of the blockchain (i.e. is not "synchronised")
- You sent the money to the wrong address somehow.

Answer (score 2):

The transaction is confirmed. Make sure that you have sent to the correct address (your friend's address `37ZyDkjmMEkTVjeuLcjH3p5AQEZF5tpr1E`).

If you are sure then your friend is trying to scam you because in transaction https://blockstream.info/tx/cb2b8b9fe545ba2705f9831e33417cdf3c4c749eb738cb359d3c3af4834b2768 the UTXO you sent to your friend has been spent.